# Is the phrase "large number core machine" correct?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, compounds

I would like to use the following phrase for a machine with large number cores. Is this correct? Please let me know.

`large number core machine`

Comment: Do you mean "with a large number of cores", or is a large number core a core which is specially designed to handle large numbers?

Comment: I mean "with a large number of cores".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Large number core machine" sounds like clumsy or incorrect English.  If you are talking about computers, the only grammatically-plausible interpretation that occurs to me is "Large number-core machine"; but that phrase is not semantically plausible because "number-core" is not a phrase used in the computer field.

Whether the previously-suggested *many-core* term is what you are looking for isn't clear.  Some nuances noted in the wikipedia [multi-core_processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) description may rule it out:
"A many-core processor is a multi-core processor in which the number of cores is large enough that traditional multi-processor techniques are no longer efficient...  The many-core threshold is roughly in the range of several tens of cores...  The terms many-core and massively multi-core are sometimes used to describe multi-core architectures with an especially high number of cores (tens or hundreds)."

Note that *many-core* refers to chips that contain many CPU cores, rather than to machines with many CPU's spread across many chips, which are *multi-CPU* machines.

If you have a specific chip in mind, with a specific number of cores, terms like dual-core, tri-core, quad-core, hexa-core, and octo-core are in common use.

If what you refer to is a [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) then look for terminology specific to such chips.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question directly, "Large number" is being used here as an adjective for *core* to express multiplicity.  That is not the usual usage.  As an adjective "Large number" typically refers to something related to numbers themselves, such as "large-number arithmetic".

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor#Terminology):

> The terms *many-core* and *massively multi-core* are sometimes used to describe multi-core architectures with an especially high number of cores (tens or hundreds).

Answer (score 2):

The commonly used term for this is *many-core machine*.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with that. However, I would like to know whether the phrase "large number core machine" is correct usage or not?

Comment: "Large number core machine" doesn't sound right. "High-number-core machine" or "high-count core machine" might be a little better, and "a machine with a large number of cores" would be better yet.

Comment: Thank you. How about "machine with large number cores"?

Comment: A "machine with a large number of cores" would be correct. If you leave out the "a" and "of" it will be understandable but not correct.

Comment: Could you add your suggestions in the comments to your answer, please?